# Android app crashing after picking image from intent chooser

Tags: android, image, android-intent

Hi in my android app I am trying to open an image using the intent to choose.

In another class I have this function which opens a dialog, and by clicking an IageView in it, it opens the intent to pick a picture.

```
public void OpenImageUploadDialog() {
    final NavigationScreen context = (NavigationScreen) img.getContext();

    final Dialog imageUploadDialog = new Dialog(context);
    imageUploadDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    imageUploadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_upload_image);

    final TextView avatarStatus = (TextView) imageUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.avatar_status);
    final ImageView avatar = (ImageView) imageUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    Button addButton = (Button) imageUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
    Button cancelButton = (Button) imageUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    dialog_img = avatar;
    dialog_status = avatarStatus;

    avatar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            Intent image_chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.select_picture));
            context.startActivityForResult(image_chooser, SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isReady) {
                if (Network.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                    imageUploadDialog.dismiss();
                } else {    
                    Views.ShowErrorMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.no_internet));
                }
            } else {
                Views.ShowErrorMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.select_image_first));
            }
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageUploadDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    imageUploadDialog.show();
}
```

Then on the activity class, I have this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (imageUploadHandler != null){
            imageUploadHandler.handleResult(this, data);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the ImageView on the dialog, the intent shows up, I can then select an image. As soon as I do, it returns to the app, but the activity is white screen, then crashes after 2 seconds. Here is the log:

```
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {android.arin/android.arin.NavigationScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/11738 (has extras) }} to activity {android.arin/android.arin.NavigationScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2639)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/11738 (has extras) }} to activity {android.arin/android.arin.NavigationScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     ... 12 more
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.arin.NavigationScreen.onActivityResult(NavigationScreen.java:181)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5361)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
06-20 18:24:02.465: E/AndroidRuntime(9254):     ... 13 more
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the line numbers here, but I'm guessing NavigationScreen.java:181 is

imageUploadHandler.handleResult(this, data);

and that imageUploadHandler is null (for some reason; that code's not shown). In any case, it looks like that NPE is pointing to NavigationScreen.java:181 and you should look there.

Comment: Yes line 181 is that. Also I updated the code above. I check if its null. But it didnt help. Well it didnt crash, but the screen still went white, then went back to the activity with the dialog closed, and it didnt execute `imageUploadHandler.handleResult(this, data);`... I tried debugging, but the debugger loses connection after I select the pic (i.e. I can't click next step). I put a breakpoint on `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`, but it didn't stop there...